# Como fazer uma subquery no laravel eloquent com WHERE

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Ola, estou utilizando o laravel 5.6 e estou criando uma query de consulta utilizando o laravel eloquent, porem estou com dificuldades de criar uma subquery

o que eu quero criar é simples no SQL server:

```
    ,DT_ALTA = (SELECT TOP(1) 
                        DH_DESOSPITALIZACAO 
                    FROM 
                        TB_CAPTA_EVO_STATUS_CAES AS CAES 
                    WHERE 
                        (CAES.ID_CD_INTERNACAO = CAIN.ID_CD_INTERNACAO
                        AND  FL_DESOSPITALIZACAO IN (4, 5, 6, 16, 19) )
                        OR (CAES.ID_CD_INTERNACAO = CAIN.ID_CD_INTERNACAO
                        AND   FL_FINALIZACAO = 'S')
                    ORDER BY CAES.DH_DESOSPITALIZACAO DESC)
```

Porem via laravel eloquent estou com dificuldades, segue minha query:

```
  $mot = db::table('TB_CAPTA_INTERNACAO_CAIN as CAIN')
                            ->join('TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP as CRMP','CAIN.ID_CD_PACIENTE','=','CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA')
                            ->join('TB_CAPTA_CFG_ORIGEM_CAGO as CAGO','CAIN.ID_CD_ORIGEM','=','CAGO.ID_CD_ORIGEM')
                            ->join('TB_CRM_PACIENTES_CRPC as CRPC','CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA','=','CRPC.ID_CD_PESSOA')
                            //->join('TB_CAPTA_EVO_STATUS_CAES as CAES','CAES.ID_CD_INTERNACAO','=','CAIN.ID_CD_INTERNACAO')
                            ->select('CAIN.ID_CD_INTERNACAO','CAIN.DH_ADMISSAO_HOSP','CAIN.DH_INICIO_ACOMPANHAMENTO','CRMP.NM_PESSOA','CRMP.NM_SOBRENOME','CAGO.DS_TITULO','CRPC.NR_CREDENCIAL','CRMP.DH_NASCIMENTO','CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA')
                            ->where('IN_SITUACAO',$request->get('situacao'));
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar fico agradecido desde ja.

Consegui resolver, segue o codigo da resolução:

```
->addSelect(db::raw("(SELECT TOP 1 CAES.DH_DESOSPITALIZACAO FROM TB_CAPTA_EVO_STATUS_CAES as CAES WHERE CAES.ID_CD_INTERNACAO = CAIN.ID_CD_INTERNACAO) as DH_DESOSPITALIZACAO" ))
```

eu adicionei esse trecho no eloquent, ele faz a subquery certinha.

Comment: Coloca sua consulta inteira. Parece que está pela metade.

Comment: Voce diz a consulta do SQL server ou do eloquent? a do SQL server é uma procedure muito grande, e a do Eloquent não tem mais muita coisa, apenas order by e etc

Answer (score 1):

Se eu captei, a sua dificuldade está em montar uma consulta do tipo:

```
WHERE (condicao1 AND condicao2) OR (condicao3 AND condicao4)
```

Um outro detalhe é que condicao1 e condicao3 são iguais, então daria pra fazer:

```
WHERE condicao1 AND (condicao2 OR condicao4)
```

Mas acontece que em condicao1 você precisa comparar uma coluna com outra, então eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
$consulta->whereRaw('CAES.ID_CD_INTERNACAO = CAIN.ID_CD_INTERNACAO')
   ->where(function($query) {
      return $query->where(condicao2)->orWhere(condicao4);
})
```

E em condicao2 e condicao4 você passa os parametros `[atributo do modelo]`, `operador lógico` e `[valor a comparar]`. Caso necessite utilizar cláusulas em SQL puro puro, utilize `whereRaw' ou 'orWhereRaw`.